# Approaches for porting content from one SPList to another SPList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splist, copy-content

I have one SPList -say List1- with some 400 items with single line of text, dropdown, lookup,peoplepicker, multiline fields etc.
I need to copy the entire from this List1 to a new list that has different set of columns.if List1 has 30 columns then my new list List2 has 46 columns. 
How do I perform this?

I do not have Central Admin access for this application. 
What should be the approach for achieving this:

Should I go with `CSOM` within a  CEWP? If `CSOM`, can anyone please provide  source/links

Should I use C# coding, if this is the approach, I can't use `Server Side OM`  as I am not working on the server

Comment: Just make a list template of the list from site settings, include the content and use the template to create "List2" and add the additional columns. No code needed.

Comment: That wont work.I already tried as my source list columns and target list columns are different.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Powershell.

Comment: @SaMolPP, i misunderstood your question.

Comment: @DylanCristy, i don't have access to the server where SP is installed. I have access upto site collec.admin ONLY. So cant think of  writing PS Script.

Answer (score 1):

This only clones/duplicates an item in the currect list, so you have to add

- Create a second list B (not in this code)
- loop items in list A (not in this code)
- create item in list B (n)
- use while loop (e,f) to loop List A fields
- write required fields to list B (n,m,v)

  ```
  function cloneItem(id) {
  var c = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
      l = c.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()),
      i = l.getItemById(id),
      f = l.get_fields(),
      n, e, d, m, v,
      url = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
  c.load(i);
  c.load(f);
  c.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
          n = l.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
          e = f.getEnumerator();
          while (e.moveNext()) {
              d = e.get_current();
              m = d.get_internalName();
              if (!(d.get_readOnlyField() 
                     || d.get_hidden() 
                     || ['Attachments', 'ContentType'].indexOf(m) > -1)
                 ) {
                  v = i.get_item(m);
                  if (v) n.set_item(m, v);
              }
          }
          n.update();
          c.load(n);
          c.executeQueryAsync(function () {
              var newID=n.get_id();
          })
      })
  ```

  }